# Django - Media Files going on 404 in Production (Azure Storage)

Tags: python, django, azure

Upon deploying an application to the azure app server, for media files, I am referring to the azure blob storage.  I am using https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/azure.html docs.

I have written these lines of code in my **settings.py** file.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'index.custom_azure.AzureMediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'index.custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{STATIC_LOCATION}/'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{MEDIAFILES_LOCATION}/'
```

In the custom_azure.py file I have included my classes

from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage

```
class AzureMediaStorage(AzureStorage):
    account_name = 'ACCOUNT_NAME' # Must be replaced by your <storage_account_name>
    account_key = 'KEY' # Must be replaced by your <storage_account_key>
    azure_container = 'media'
    expiration_secs = None
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False

class AzureStaticStorage(AzureStorage):
    account_name = 'MY_STORAGE' # Must be replaced by your storage_account_name
    account_key = 'My_KEY' # Must be replaced by your <storage_account_key>
    azure_container = 'static'
    expiration_secs = None
```

My urls.py file is like this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('index.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns +=  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am trying to refer the <http//domain.com/media/abc.png> but unfortunately, it's going on 404.

Any help appreciated!